# Grails defining List of objects as embedded in domain causes GrailsDataBinder issue

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I'm using Grails 2.2.1 with Mongo gorm.

I have a few domains that have relationships of embedded Collections of other domain objects such as:

```
class User {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    List<UserProfile> userProfiles

    static embedded = [
        'userProfiles'
    ]
    ...
```

Whenever I persist an object like this I get a message in my log:

> ERROR binding.GrailsDataBinder
>     - Unable to auto-create type interface java.util.List, class java.lang.InstantiationException thrown in constructor

Even though I get this message, it still works and a List of those UserProfile objects is embedded as expected. I saw somewhere that grails tries to instantiate the interface for embedded objects for some reason.

I've seen people do this:

```
List<UserProfile> userProfiles = []
```

but then you obviously lose the ability to use a nullable constraint. I'm sure declaring it:

```
ArrayList<UserProfile> userProfiles
```

would maybe work but I'm not up for that. Is there a way to declare relationships like this as embedded without getting this error?

Comment: Why are you "not up for that"? If you declared `List<UserProfile> userProfiles = []` then you would be specifying that the `List` is an `ArrayList` anyway. Why not just give that variable a type?

Comment: Also, have you tried `static hasMany = [userProfiles: UserProfile]` instead of `List<UserProfile> userProfiles`?

Comment: @grantmc I would just rather not define an implementation.. I want the framework to decide what it should be. I did try a hasMany declaration, but then it complained about auto-creation of interface Set instead.